# Need to locate a button by matching the heading text under span

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, xpath, protractor

How can I locate a button by matching the heading text under span?
In the html mentioned below, I want to locate the buttons based on the text under `< h3>` tag i.e **'Activities'** and **'Agents'** .
As both the buttons have almost similar element structure and they both reside under the same parent.
I am writing scripts using protractor and jasmine.

This is my html:

```
<div class="left-hand-elements layout-column flex-none" flex="none" layout="column">
<div>
   <span class="layout-row" layout="row">
      <h3 class="md-title section-header flex" flex="">Activities</h3>
      <button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="prov.showAddNew('activities', 'create')" aria-label="addCreate New">
         <md-icon class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope material-icons">add</md-icon>
         <span class="ng-scope">Create New</span>
      </button>
   </span>
   <md-list class="record-list md-whiteframe-2dp" role="list"></div>
</div>
<div>
   <span class="layout-row" layout="row">
      <h3 class="md-title section-header flex" flex="">Agents</h3>
      <button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" type="button" ng-click="prov.showAddNew('agents', 'create')" aria-label="addCreate New">
         <md-icon class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope material-icons">add</md-icon>
         <span class="ng-scope">Create New</span>
      </button>
   </span>
   <md-list class="record-list md-whiteframe-2dp" role="list"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below xpaths:
For the Activities header:

```
//*[@class="layout-row"]/h3[text()="Activities"]
```

For the Agents header:

```
//*[@class="layout-row"]/h3[text()="Agents"]
```

For finding the button next to the header you can try the below xpath:

```
//*[@class="layout-row"]/h3[text()="Activities"]//..//button
```

and

```
//*[@class="layout-row"]/h3[text()="Activities"]//..//button
```

The xpath will navigate to the parent element after finding the header and then find the button tag.

For more information on xpaths you can view the below link:
http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php

Comment: Thanks Nitesh. With these I can locate the two headers. But I need to click the button based on the header text. Any idea how to do that?